# How to get user apps with facebook sdk?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want get user's app with facebook sdk, i have found facebook document and not get any idea.

Apps like these.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the list of Apps anymore, earlier you could use this endpoint: `/me/applications/developer`

The result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) User/applications endpoint is deprecated for versions v2.6 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "Gk8yWCyLdK3"
  }
}
```